# How to solve Timeout when starting spring boot with cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-run

I want to launch spring boot module on CloudRun.
CloudRun has GCLB, So before the boot of the spring boot module complete, it will be incorporated into the cluster when communication at the TCP level becomes possible.

do you know how to solve this probrem?

Answer (score 1):

When a request comes in on Cloud Run service that has scaled to 0, a new instance is created. The request is kept about 10s waiting the instance starts.

However, if your instance start take too much time, the request can't be served and you have an error (HTTP 429).

To solve that, you have 3 solutions:

- Speed up the cold start of Cloud Run instances. You can try [APPCDS](https://medium.com/@toparvion/appcds-for-spring-boot-applications-first-contact-6216db6a4194) or [GraalVM packaging](https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/03/spring-native-beta-available/).
- Set the [min-instance](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances) to a value > 0 to always keep an instance warm (it's not free but it helps you a lot for few)
- Continue to use JAVA but not SpringBoot, or use another languages that start quicker (Go is great!).